# Group by of 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query gets me results but I want to only group by name & month & sum the Title & number of learners

```
WITH t
     AS (  SELECT b.name,
                  TO_CHAR (t.start_on, 'MON') MONTH,
                  COUNT (q.title) title,
                  SUM (t.learners) No_of_Learners
             FROM lms$training T
                  INNER JOIN
                  lms$qualifications q
                     ON     t.qualification_id = q.qualification_id
                        AND TO_DATE (t.start_on, 'DD/MON/YY') BETWEEN 

              '01/JAN/17'
                                                                      AND 
                '30/APR/17'
                            AND t.event_type <> 'Learnership' --and 
                 t.branch_id = 1000001541
                      INNER JOIN gl$branches b ON b.branch_id = t.branch_id

              GROUP BY b.name,
                      q.title,
                      t.learners,
                      t.start_on)
             SELECT NAME,
             MONTH,
             TITLE,
             No_of_Learners
            FROM t

          ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Results

```
NAME Month Title No_of_Learners
Cape APR      1       5
Cape APR      2       5
DUR  MAY      1       6
```

Expecting  Results

```
NAME Month Title No_of_Learners
Cape APR      3      10     
DUR  MAY      1       6
```

Comment: why don't you try removing `t.learners` from the `group by` clause

Comment: Include sample pseudo code to analyse the issue.

Comment: Want name of branch training per month with total training titles & learners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the number of courses given per month. If this is correct you can use the following query:

```
SELECT b.name,
       TO_CHAR (t.start_on, 'MON') MONTH,
       COUNT (DISTINCT q.title) title,
       SUM (t.learners) No_of_Learners
FROM lms$training T
INNER JOIN lms$qualifications q
        ON     t.qualification_id = q.qualification_id
           AND TO_DATE (t.start_on, 'DD/MON/YY') BETWEEN '01/JAN/17'
                                                     AND '30/APR/17'
           AND t.event_type <> 'Learnership' --and  t.branch_id = 1000001541
INNER JOIN gl$branches b ON b.branch_id = t.branch_id
GROUP BY b.name,
         TO_CHAR (t.start_on, 'MON')
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t
     AS (  SELECT b.name,
                  TO_CHAR (t.start_on, 'MON') MONTH,
                  COUNT (q.title) title,
                  SUM (t.learners) No_of_Learners
             FROM lms$training T
                  INNER JOIN
                  lms$qualifications q
                     ON     t.qualification_id = q.qualification_id
                        AND TO_DATE (t.start_on, 'DD/MON/YY') BETWEEN '01/JAN/17'
                                                                  AND '30/APR/17'
                        AND t.event_type <> 'Learnership' -- and    t.branch_id = 1000001541
                  INNER JOIN gl$branches b ON b.branch_id = t.branch_id
         GROUP BY b.name, q.title, t.start_on)
  SELECT NAME,
         MONTH,
         SUM (TITLE),
         SUM (No_of_Learners)
    FROM t
GROUP BY NAME, MONTH
ORDER BY 1, 2
```